# Directory not found for option warning

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I've downloaded `Facebook SDK` and imported manually to my project throw link `binary` with `library`. And what I am having here is that after closing the project I get two warnings say:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/user/Desktop/iOS/Source Code/projectname/Controls/Facebook'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FSDK'
```

And when I try to run the project I get:

```
/Users/user/Desktop/iOS/Source Code/projectname/ViewControllers/RegistrationViewController.h:14:9: error: 'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h' file not found
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/user/Desktop/iOS/Source Code/projectname/ViewControllers/projectname-Bridging-Header.h'
```

So each time I run the app I have to remove the `Facebook frameworks` and add them again so the error disappear but the warning is still there ! Any solution ?

Comment: See this [quick solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046676/file-not-found-in-bridging-header-when-importing-objective-c-frameworks-into-s/34046677#34046677)

Answer (score 0):

In your project have a HeaderFile to use Objective-C Class in swift. if doen't then make Headerfile as below name.

1. Make Header file.

   ```
   projectname-Bridging-Header.h
   ```
2. adding `#import "FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h`. in Header file.
3. go to Project > Build Setting
4. search `Objective-C bridging Header`

[image]

5. drag and drop Header file. if file path is already then remove and add again as below.

[image]

[How to use Swift with ObjectiveC project.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Comment: i am using swift class in objective-c and the way around.

Comment: see update with link, use Swift in objective C, follow above link